# Grails - Interface rather than abstract class

Tags: grails, interface

I want to include "created" and "modified" fields in all of my domain classes and would like to embrace the DRY principle if possible. I don't want to extend each class as I cannot do that for a second time so instead, I'm trying to implement an interface.

Consider:

```
interface AutoTimeStamp{

  Date created
  Date modified
}

class Dog implements AutoTimeStamp{
  String breed
}

class Cat implements AutoTimeStamp{
  String noOfLives
}
```

But when I try to create a new Dog or Cat I get:

> Cannot set the property 'created' because the backing field is
>   final.

Any idea as to why this appears to be illegal? This works like a charm as an extended class.

Comment: Look at [**autotimeStamp**](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/autoTimestamp.html). You would not need any interface.

Comment: @dmahapatro you should make this an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer is correct, to define an interface that has properties you need to do:

```
interface AutoTimeStamp{

   Date getCreated()
   void setCreated(Date created)
   Date getModified()
   void setModified(Date modified)
}
```

Then in the implementing classes you can define the properties

```
Date created
Date modified
```

Answer (score 1):

`dateCreated` and `lastUpdated` is available in domain class by default.

If you want to disable **[`autoTimestamp`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/autoTimestamp.html)** then use:

```
static mapping = {
    autoTimestamp false
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just coming back to this a bit late. Am I missing something with the above? I presume I still have to add "Date dateCreated" and "Date lastUpdated" to each Domain class?

Comment: yes, correct. If you have specific columns for them then they can be mapped in `mappings` block.

Comment: Ok, the original intent was to have this abstracted out to a super class of sorts such that each domain that needs this functionality just implements or extends. Obviously the former being the preferred option. I guess the preferred option is not really possible.

Comment: Whichever class does not need the `autoTimestamp` it can be turned off as `autoTimestamp` false as shown in the answer. I do not understand except abstraction, what else is gained using a separate class/interface. :)

Comment: But to implement your solution, you have to include the two variables, dateCreate and lastUpdated right? They're not included by means of some Grails magic?

Comment: Classes/interface are not inherited by any java/groovy/grails magic as well, it has to be written. :)How different it is to go to the classes and write `extends Abc` or `implements Abc` Where Abc is the parent class or interface? Moreover, if column name is diff for each table, anyhow we have to map it. I hope you get my point. I am not gaining anything more except a new interface in the code base, if I feel it is a gain. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not forget that Groovy interfaces follow the same philosophy as Java interfaces. As such for every property in a Groovy interface:

```
PropertyType propertyName
```

means:

```
public static final PropertyType propertyName
```

You can also have a look here, please have a look on Guillaume Laforge's posts ;)

http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/RFE-interface-properties-td386038.html